# How to retrieve a MySQL Database field with data between brackets {} as an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, magento, datafield

I need to retrieve data from this table in magento `sales_flat_quote_payment`. There is a field in the table called `additional_data`.

In the `additional_data` field is data within brackets `{ }`

[image: additional data]

Here is how the data looks formatted

```
a:6:{
    s:14:"component_mode";
    s:4:"ebay";
    s:14:"payment_method";
    s:6:"PayPal";
    s:16:"channel_order_id";
    s:9:"123654789";
    s:17:"channel_final_fee";
    d:5.3600000000000003;
    s:12:"transactions";
    a:1:{
        i:0;
        a:4:{
            s:14:"transaction_id";
            s:15:"987456321456987";
            s:3:"sum";
            d:66.989999999999995;
            s:3:"fee";
            d:1.5700000000000001;
            s:16:"transaction_date";
            s:19:"2016-03-31 02:54:18";
            }
        }
    s:6:"tax_id";
    s:0:"";
}
```

How could I access this data like an array?

I specifically need to extract from this data the `s:3:"fee";` value of `d:1.5700000000000001;`.

I tried `$additional_data->transactions->fee` without success.

Here is my code I use.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");

if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("database", $con);

$po = $_GET['po'];


if( ! is_numeric($po) )
  die('invalid PO#');

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM `sales_flat_quote` WHERE `reserved_order_id` LIKE '" . $po . "' LIMIT 0 , 30";

$get_entity_id = mysql_query($query1);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_entity_id, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  $entity_id = $row['entity_id'];

  echo "  <div style='margin:30px 0px;'>
      entity_id: $entity_id<br />
    </div>
  ";
}

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM `sales_flat_quote_payment` WHERE `quote_id` = " . $entity_id . " LIMIT 0 , 30";

$get_additional_data = mysql_query($query2);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_additional_data, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  $additional_data = $row['additional_data'];

  echo "  <div style='margin:30px 0px;'>
      additional_data: $additional_data<br />
    </div>
  ";
}

  echo "  <div style='margin:30px 0px;'>
      fee: $additional_data->transactions->fee<br />
    </div>
  ";

mysql_close($con);
```

**UPdate:** I unserialized the array. Now it looks like this.

```
array(6) {

     ["component_mode"]=> string(4) "ebay"
     ["payment_method"]=> string(6) "PayPal"
     ["channel_order_id"]=> string(9) "123654789"
     ["channel_final_fee"]=> float(3.6)
     ["transactions"]=> array(1) {
         [0]=> array(4) {
         ["transaction_id"]=> string(15) "987456321456987"
         ["sum"]=> float(45)
         ["fee"]=> float(1.16)
         ["transaction_date"]=> string(19) "2016-03-31 05:43:43"
         }
    }
    ["tax_id"]=> string(0) ""
}
```

I'm still having trouble retrieving the data I want from this array.

I want to retrieve `$additional_data->transactions->fee`.

How can I do this?

Comment: isn't that a serialized array? just unserialize it

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll start there.

Comment: I unserialized it. Please read my update above. I still can't retrieve the data I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a serialized array. See [unserialize() php doc](http://php.net/unserialize)

The fee can be retrieved with :  `$additional_data['transactions'][0]["fee"]`

Comment: Ok good. I unserialized it and updated my post with how the array looks unserialized. How would I go about retrieving the data I want now. Please read my update above.

Comment: Since the fee field is the first key of transations array, you may access it with $additional_data['transactions'][0]["fee"]

Comment: I accessed it like this `$tags = $additional_data['transactions'][0]; $tags[fee]`